Equivalent of Kronecker delta for set unions
Assume I have two vectors $a = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ and $b = (b_1, b_2, ... b_m)$ that I'd like to combine with some operation $f$, such that $$f(a, b| M) = \sum_{i, j}a_iM_{ij}b_j\ . \tag{1}$$
This is nothing other than matrix multiplication, where the details of the double sum depend on the values of $M_{ij}$.  If $n = m$, and $M = I_n$, then the individual elements $M$ can be represented by the Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$, and the expression reduces to the scalar product $$f(a, b|I_n) = \sum_{i,j} a_i \delta_{ij}b_j = \sum_i a_ib_i = a \cdot b\ .$$
I'd like to find an analog for sets.  Imagine that I have the sets $D$ and $E$ that are partitioned into subsets $D_i$ and $E_j$, respectively, such that
\begin{align}
D = \bigcup_i D_i \tag{2} \\
E = \bigcup_j E_j \tag{3}
\end{align}
The case of the Cartesian product is straightforward $$D \times E = \bigcup_iD_i \times \bigcup_j E_j = \bigcup_{i,j} D_i \times E_j \tag{4}$$
but I was hoping I could find something more general than this.  In particular, is there some construction similar to equation 1 for set unions that would allow something like $$g(D, E|S) = \bigcup_{i,j} D_i \,\square_S\, E_j $$
where $\square_S$ represents some relation between $D_i$ and $E_j$ that allows something like:
\begin{eqnarray}
g(D, E|J_{n,m}) &=& \bigcup_{i,j} D_i 1 \times E_j = \bigcup_{i,j} D_i \times E_j \quad \mbox{where $J_{n,m}$ is the all-ones matrix} \tag{5} \\
g(D, E|I_n) & = & \bigcup_{i,j} D_i \delta_{ij} \times E_j = \bigcup_i D_i \times E_i \quad \mbox{where $I_n$ is the identity matrix} \tag{6}\\
\end{eqnarray}
Equations 5 and 6 must be gibberish, but are there concepts like this somewhere about how to express arbitrary unions in similar ways?

$$D={D_1,\dots,D_n}=\bigcup_i D_i$$ is an abuse of notation. The word "partition" already implies $D$ is the union of the $D_i,$ but the middle part of this expression is nonsensical.

Thanks, @ThomasAndrews.  Adjusted accordingly.

After thinking about this some more, I think the solution is to rely on set-builder notation:
\begin{equation}
(,|)=\{(d,e) \in D_i \times E_j\,|\, i \in I, j \in J, S(i, j)\}
\end{equation}
where $I$ and $J$ are index sets corresponding to equations 2 and 3 in the OP, and $S(i, j)$ is a predicate that evaluates to true for the desired combinations of $i$ and $j$.
